# Is it possible to run multiple CUDA version on windows?

Tags: cuda, pytorch, nvidia, torchvision

I am doing an experiment on a chest x-ray Project. and I want multiple versions of the CUDA toolkit but the problem is that my system put the latest version which I installed lastly is appearing.
Is it possible to run any of CUDA like 9.0, 10.2, 11.0 as required to GitHub code?

I have done all the initial steps like path added to an environment variable and added CUDNN copied file and added to the environment.
Now the problem is that I want to use Cuda 9.0 as per my code but my default setting put cuda.11.0 what is the solution or script to switch easily between these version

Comment: you can run multiple CUDA versions on windows.  If you install the latest driver for your GPU it will support any CUDA recent version you select.  No need to change drivers.  The CUDA toolkits get installed in different locations so they can live side-by-side.  However you will need to modify paths appropriately and select versions to use in VS appropriately.  And a single application (compiled executable) cannot simultaneously use two different CUDA versions, but I don't think you are asking that.  Two different apps can use two different CUDA versions.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I know and I search a lot to have multiple CUDA and I added path also and I have the drivers too.
Now I want to use cuda 9.0 and don't want to use other 10 or 11 cuda. I have driver of all version and I installed each of them.
Let me correct if I want to use cuda 9 should install that compatible version of cuda 9 driver? or install the latest one>?

Comment: The latest driver will work properly with CUDA 9.

Comment: But nvidia-smi put CUDA 10.2
and my code put 11.0 and I want CUDA 9.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may set CUDA_PATH_V9_0, CUDA_PATH_V10_0, etc properly, then set CUDA_PATH to any one of them (e.g. CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0).

Then in your VS project, set your cuda library path using the CUDA_PATH (e.g. $CUDA_PATH\lib).

To switch, just set the CUDA_PATH to another version, and clean & rebuild your VS project(s).

Comment: The answer was not satisfactory. I already mentioned that I added paths in the system variable and in the virtual variable too. The problem is to use the CUDA different version.
Now I have 9, 10 and 11 cuda and I want the old one and I installed cuda 11 latest cuda driver. So should I use the older version driver of cuda 9 and again install to get to cuda 9 by default or just change the VS project cuda path,
GIve me an example where should I change in VS code during code.

Comment: You can always use the latest driver and only use one driver. You should be able to simply point your CUDA_PATH to the desired one in your VS project settings, without changing your code.

Comment: If you want to use some CUDA feature that is not available across all cuda versions, then check the value of the macro __CUDA_ARCH__ in your code and write different code for different CUDA architecture, and change the "Code Generation" settings under CUDA C/C++ --> Device, to the correct one, e.g. "compute_30,sm_30". See [https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition/3.2/Content/CUDA_Properties_Config.htm] for details